# Problems downloading files with WGET

Tags: wget

I am trying to use WGET to download files from a server.
I am using a batch file with the following line:

`wget -q http://subs.ro/get/22463`

The file is downloaded but the name is wrong and there is no file extension, when I try to download the same file using IE or MF, I get usually an archive (rar or Zip).

Any help will be appreciated.

C.

Comment: this is more apropos for superuser or serverfault.

Comment: I am trying to put together a little program for personal use that can download subtitles from that site.

Answer (score 3):

Use the `--content-disposition` option to `wget`.

Comment: I am not sure how to use that option, I tried using it directly
wget --content-disposition h*t*tp://subs.ro/get/22463
and this is what I got
C:\Users\>wget --content-disposition http://subs.ro/get/22463
wget: unrecognized option `--content-disposition'
Usage: wget [OPTION]... [URL]...

Try `wget --help' for more options.

I can't find any other details on this oprion even on google.

Thx. C.

Comment: i am using the GnuWin32 wget 1.11.4 on Windows, and it has the --content-disposition option (though marked as experimental). try [upgrading your version of wget](http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/packages/wget.htm)

Comment: The manual here describes it: http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html. It does say that it's "experimental". You probably have an older version of wget.

Comment: I have the latest version as well, I just needed to add '', unfortunately it still doesn't work, same thing as before.

Answer (score 2):

I just ran the same command (on the same link) and then checked what downloaded:

```
$ file 22463
22463: Zip archive data, at least v2.0 to extract
```

Unzip confirms:

```
$ unzip -tl 22463
Archive:  22463
    testing: Paranormal Activity.srt   OK
No errors detected in compressed data of 22463.
```

Now, since what you download *is* a zipfile, you just need to rename it.  To do this from `wget`, you can use the `-O` (capital letter) switch:

```
$ wget http://subs.ro/get/22463 -O foo.zip
[...]
2009-10-31 16:42:56 (39.1 KB/s) - `foo.zip' saved [30656/30656]
```